# Website down due to htaccess why? please

Tags: .htaccess

My website was down for more than 8 hours it started before midnight.
I called godaddy everything is okay as my other websites are good.
It wwas not my CDN as I changed the DNS back to the Godaddy provided DNS

I erased my htaccess and my website went up

below is my htaccess, what could have gone wrong. There were no problems before why did it suddenly stop?

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
    # Enable HackRepair.com's blacklist feature - Security > Settings > Banned Users > Default Blacklist
    # Start HackRepair.com Blacklist
    RewriteEngine on
    # Start Abuse Agent Blocking
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*Indy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*NEWT" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Maxthon$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SeaMonkey$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Acunetix" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^binlar" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BlackWidow" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bolt 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BOT for JCE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bot mailto\:craftbot@yahoo\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^casper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^checkprivacy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ChinaClaw" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^clshttp" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^cmsworldmap" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^comodo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Custo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Default Browser 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^diavol" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DIIbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DISCo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^dotbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Download Demon" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^eCatch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EirGrabber" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailCollector" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailSiphon" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailWolf" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Express WebPictures" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^extract" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ExtractorPro" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EyeNetIE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^feedfinder" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FHscan" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FlashGet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^flicky" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^g00g1e" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetRight" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetWeb\!" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\!Zilla" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\-Ahead\-Got\-It" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^grab" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GrabNet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Grafula" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^harvest" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^HMView" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ia_archiver" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Stripper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InterGET" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Internet Ninja" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InternetSeer\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^jakarta" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Java" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JetCar" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JOC Web Spider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kanagawa" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kmccrew" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^larbin" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^LeechFTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^libwww" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mass Downloader" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^microsoft\.url" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MIDown tool" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^miner" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mister PiX" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MSFrontPage" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Navroad" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NearSite" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Net Vampire" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetAnts" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetZIP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^nutch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Octopus" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Explorer" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Navigator" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PageGrabber" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Papa Foto" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pavuk" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pcBrowser" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PeoplePal" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^planetwork" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^psbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^purebot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pycurl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^RealDownload" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ReGet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Rippers 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sitecheck\.internetseer\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SiteSnagger" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^skygrid" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SmartDownload" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperHTTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Surfbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^tAkeOut" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Teleport Pro" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Toata dragostea mea pentru diavola" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^turnit" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^vikspider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^VoidEYE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Web Image Collector" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Web Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebAuto" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebBandit" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebCopier" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebFetch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebGo IS" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebLeacher" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebReaper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebSauger" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website eXtractor" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website Quester" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebStripper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebWhacker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebZIP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Wget" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Widow" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WPScan" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWW\-Mechanize" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWWOFFLE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Xaldon WebSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Zeus" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^zmeu" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "360Spider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "AhrefsBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "CazoodleBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "discobot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "EasouSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ecxi" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "GT\:\:WWW" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "heritrix" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTP\:\:Lite" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTrack" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ia_archiver" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "id\-search" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IDBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Indy Library" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IRLbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ISC Systems iRc Search 2\.1" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksCrawler" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksManager\.com_bot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "linkwalker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "lwp\-trivial" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MFC_Tear_Sample" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Microsoft URL Control" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Missigua Locator" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MJ12bot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "panscient\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PECL\:\:HTTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PHPCrawl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PleaseCrawl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SBIder" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SearchmetricsBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SeznamBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Snoopy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Steeler" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "URI\:\:Fetch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "urllib" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Web Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "webalta" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WebCollage" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Wells Search II" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WEP Search" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "XoviBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "YisouSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "zermelo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ZyBorg" [NC,OR]
    # End Abuse Agent Blocking
    # Start Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?semalt\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?kambasoft\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?savetubevideo\.com" [NC]
    # End Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
    # End HackRepair.com Blacklist, http://pastebin.com/u/hackrepair

    # Ban Hosts - Security > Settings > Banned Users
    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^46\.53\.183\.105$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^46\.53\.183\.105$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^46\.53\.183\.105$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^46\.105\.14\.54$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^46\.105\.14\.54$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^46\.105\.14\.54$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^114\.113\.145\.149$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^114\.113\.145\.149$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^114\.113\.145\.149$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^5\.248\.41\.27$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^5\.248\.41\.27$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^5\.248\.41\.27$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^95\.163\.121\.129$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^95\.163\.121\.129$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^95\.163\.121\.129$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^208\.49\.103\.77$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^208\.49\.103\.77$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^208\.49\.103\.77$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^8\.37\.70\.4$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^8\.37\.70\.4$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^8\.37\.70\.4$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^8\.37\.70\.33$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^8\.37\.70\.33$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^8\.37\.70\.33$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^208\.49\.103\.90$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^208\.49\.103\.90$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^208\.49\.103\.90$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^64\.215\.255\.164$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^64\.215\.255\.164$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^64\.215\.255\.164$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^193\.201\.224\.167$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^193\.201\.224\.167$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^193\.201\.224\.167$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^46\.183\.219\.133$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^46\.183\.219\.133$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^46\.183\.219\.133$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^93\.179\.69\.55$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^93\.179\.69\.55$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^93\.179\.69\.55$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^46\.148\.18\.162$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^46\.148\.18\.162$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^46\.148\.18\.162$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^88\.80\.196\.2$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^88\.80\.196\.2$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^88\.80\.196\.2$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^188\.120\.246\.106$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^188\.120\.246\.106$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^188\.120\.246\.106$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^185\.129\.148\.205$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^185\.129\.148\.205$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^185\.129\.148\.205$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^46\.161\.9\.8$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^46\.161\.9\.8$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^46\.161\.9\.8$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^154\.16\.166\.28$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^154\.16\.166\.28$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^154\.16\.166\.28$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^185\.109\.144\.236$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^185\.109\.144\.236$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^185\.109\.144\.236$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^91\.200\.12\.121$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^91\.200\.12\.121$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^91\.200\.12\.121$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^142\.4\.216\.32$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^142\.4\.216\.32$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^142\.4\.216\.32$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^193\.201\.225\.85$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^193\.201\.225\.85$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^193\.201\.225\.85$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^37\.58\.52\.30$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^37\.58\.52\.30$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^37\.58\.52\.30$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^193\.201\.225\.21$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^193\.201\.225\.21$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^193\.201\.225\.21$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^174\.31\.138\.26$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^174\.31\.138\.26$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^174\.31\.138\.26$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^94\.180\.109\.24$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^94\.180\.109\.24$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^94\.180\.109\.24$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^195\.154\.230\.160$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^195\.154\.230\.160$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^195\.154\.230\.160$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^37\.216\.217\.11$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^37\.216\.217\.11$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^37\.216\.217\.11$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^89\.237\.153\.250$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^89\.237\.153\.250$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^89\.237\.153\.250$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^8\.37\.70\.164$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^8\.37\.70\.164$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^8\.37\.70\.164$" DenyAccess

    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <RequireAll>
            Require all granted
            Require not env DenyAccess
            Require not ip 46.53.183.105
            Require not ip 46.105.14.54
            Require not ip 114.113.145.149
            Require not ip 5.248.41.27
            Require not ip 95.163.121.129
            Require not ip 208.49.103.77
            Require not ip 8.37.70.4
            Require not ip 8.37.70.33
            Require not ip 208.49.103.90
            Require not ip 64.215.255.164
            Require not ip 193.201.224.167
            Require not ip 46.183.219.133
            Require not ip 93.179.69.55
            Require not ip 46.148.18.162
            Require not ip 88.80.196.2
            Require not ip 188.120.246.106
            Require not ip 185.129.148.205
            Require not ip 46.161.9.8
            Require not ip 154.16.166.28
            Require not ip 185.109.144.236
            Require not ip 91.200.12.121
            Require not ip 142.4.216.32
            Require not ip 193.201.225.85
            Require not ip 37.58.52.30
            Require not ip 193.201.225.21
            Require not ip 174.31.138.26
            Require not ip 94.180.109.24
            Require not ip 195.154.230.160
            Require not ip 37.216.217.11
            Require not ip 89.237.153.250
            Require not ip 8.37.70.164
        </RequireAll>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from env=DenyAccess
        Deny from 46.53.183.105
        Deny from 46.105.14.54
        Deny from 114.113.145.149
        Deny from 5.248.41.27
        Deny from 95.163.121.129
        Deny from 208.49.103.77
        Deny from 8.37.70.4
        Deny from 8.37.70.33
        Deny from 208.49.103.90
        Deny from 64.215.255.164
        Deny from 193.201.224.167
        Deny from 46.183.219.133
        Deny from 93.179.69.55
        Deny from 46.148.18.162
        Deny from 88.80.196.2
        Deny from 188.120.246.106
        Deny from 185.129.148.205
        Deny from 46.161.9.8
        Deny from 154.16.166.28
        Deny from 185.109.144.236
        Deny from 91.200.12.121
        Deny from 142.4.216.32
        Deny from 193.201.225.85
        Deny from 37.58.52.30
        Deny from 193.201.225.21
        Deny from 174.31.138.26
        Deny from 94.180.109.24
        Deny from 195.154.230.160
        Deny from 37.216.217.11
        Deny from 89.237.153.250
        Deny from 8.37.70.164
    </IfModule>

    # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
    <files .htaccess>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.html>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.txt>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files install.php>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files wp-config.php>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>

    # Disable Directory Browsing - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Directory Browsing
    Options -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
        RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

        # Disable PHP in Uploads - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Uploads
        RewriteRule ^wp\-content/uploads/.*\.(?:php[1-6]?|pht|phtml?)$ - [NC,F]

        # Filter Request Methods - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Request Methods
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

        # Filter Suspicious Query Strings in the URL - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Suspicious Query Strings
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=jetpack-sso
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
    </IfModule>

    # Enable the hide backend feature - Security > Settings > Hide Login Area > Hide Backend
    RewriteRule ^(/)?pasok747/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(/)?register/?$ /wplogin?action=register [QSA,L]
# END iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
ress
```

Comment: Check your error logs for clues. The first place to start.

Comment: error logs is empty

Answer (score 0):

We can't help you here, because Stackoverflow is not a debugging service.

But you can try a search yourself by removing parts of the .htaccess and reactivate it. When the error disappears, the problem is most likely with the removed part. When your website still doesn't work, the problem is with one of the remaining parts. Keep removing parts until the error disappears.

When you located the offending part, you can reactivate the .htaccess with all the other parts to verify it works again. If it does, you can inspect the offending part and be more specific with your question on Stackoverflow.

You can also apply this technique to the identified directives to further limit the problematic part.

Comment: Don't answer off-topic questions - instead, please flag them
for attention and they will be closed or migrated
appropriately.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12939299)

Comment: This *does* provide an answer on how OP may solve this problem himself. And it even might help others to solve similar problems using binary search. So even if you don't recognize this as an answer, others might.

Comment: I think that makes it a comment rather than an answer.  It certainly doesn't fix the code, because this off-topic question has no code...